# How to put Audio URL into Arrays and loop out page by page?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ipad, avaudioplayer, nsurl

***This is define under viewDidLoad***
-Trying to put the URL path of audio into an array
-After putting into an array, would like to loop out page by page
-Trying to do a flip page and auto play auto play a audio of each page

## define Audio 6

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"part-%d.mp3"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];

    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 1; //repeat once

self.video =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:Audio];
for (int i=0; i <Audio; i++)
{
   [self.video addObject:paths];
}

[audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution can make `create` `one` `audio` (supported by apple guidelines) which has `all` together your all `audio`.

Now you know the `timing` of all `audio` when it gets started.Make `gobal` instance `AVAudioPlayer`.

Start `yourAudioPlayer` with one audio file.When page changes use these method:

```
[yourAudioPlayer playAtTime:timeWhenSpecificPageAudioStarts];
```